# Displacement doing wierd stuff

Tags: displacement

So i want to apply displacement map but then this happene. Any ideas?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOGUE.jpg

Comment: You should add an image of your node material to see if there is something there to help you

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this